# First 2 images of Fancybox gallery at different heights in relation to rest of gallery

Tags: css, fancybox, alignment, inline

I am in the process of implementing a fancybox gallery on a website I am developing - for some reason though the first 2 images appear at different heights of the page:

http://leedsragfashionshow.co.uk/wp/index.php/committee/

I am experiencing this on Chrome and on Firefox, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the tile of your question is misleading because a fancybox gallery is when the images are already displayed inside fancybox and not before. In your case, the issue is with the **thumbnails** of the gallery that has nothing to do with fancybox.

Anyway, why is this happening? This is because you are adding a html line break `<br />` after each link `<a>` that wraps the image `<img />` tag like:

```
<a rel="group" href="http://leedsragfashionshow.co.uk/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/committee/1.jpg" class="fancybox"><img alt="" src="http://leedsragfashionshow.co.uk/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/committee/1.jpg" class="committee"></a><br />
<a rel="group" href="http://leedsragfashionshow.co.uk/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/committee/2.jpg" class="fancybox"><img alt="" src="http://leedsragfashionshow.co.uk/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/committee/2.jpg" class="committee"></a><br />
...etc.
```

If you are already floating the images, then you just need to remove those line breaks `<br />`. See this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WqkVx/)** with no `<br />` tags.

Comment: That worked thanks. I hadn't intentionally added the line breaks, WordPress just automatically did it - annoying.